# Como definir um tamanho para caixa de texto do EditText?

Tags: android, xml

Como definir um tamanho para caixa de texto do `EditText` para ficar um quadrado

Comment: Definir o `layout_width` igual ao `layout_height` não funciona? Ou você quer que seja quadrado a qualquer dimensão (variável)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer isto:

```
final LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(50,50); // Largura, Altura
seuEditText.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```